# Redirection rule in Outlook.com to Salesforce issue

Tags: salesforce, outlook.com

I have a website which has a contact form. The form is sent to a outlook.com email. And in this outlook.com account I have a redirection rule configured to redirect to salesforce. The funny thing is, sometimes the redirection works perfect but sometimes it does not work (I monitored in salesforce and I have no reception of email). But in those cases If  the automatic redirections fails, I do a manual redirection, and the email is received. 
Does anyone experienced a similar situation between outlook.com redirections with salesforce? Is there something related to outlook.com or salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found an issue from Salesforce. It was unrelated to office365.

Answer (score 0):

One thing i know is outlook doesn't work for mac and you may not need to use lightning outlook, not sure if this can impact but may be worth a try.

Comment: Actually I'm talking about outlook.com. I'm not using the desktop application

Comment: @MatiasK in this case you should remove the Outlook tag, since it is reserved for the Desktop Application

Comment: Sorry about that.